# Magento 1.9 rwd theme 'my downloadable products' not showing

Tags: responsive-design, magento-1.9

this is my first time posting on this site, so forgive me if it's not the perfect question.

I am creating a site using Magento, version 1.9. I'm using the RWD built-in theme and my site will sell downloadable products only. In my test purchases, everything seems to work OK, but in the customer account page the "My Downloadable Products" link isn't showing up in the navigation. I was told my theme doesn't support this, but I feel that it must support this since it comes with Magento 1.9 out of the box.

When I switch the default package in the admin->configuration->design section to a different theme, the "My Downloadable Products" navigation/page will appear. I can't seem to figure out why it doesn't show up in RWD.

So my questions are, 1) Does the RWD 1.9 theme support this feature? If so, is there something special I have to do to enable it?

Answer (score 0):

I've installed a clean Magento CE 1.9 shop, created a downloadable product, selected the "rwd" package and everything seems to work just fine. In the account page, the last link is "My Downloadable Products". What changes did you make in the theme?

Comment: I hadn't made any changes. The problem was that all the files didnt transfer so I was missing what was needed to show that menu item.